# TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in node js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I am getting an error when i run my application.

The error:

```
 MongoDB.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err.message); });
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
 ...
```

I tried to comment that part of the code out to see if i have anymore similar errors and found another same one. ( This time the word "once" )

The code:

```
var mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost/chatapp";
var MongoDB = mongoose.connect(mongoURI).connection;
MongoDB.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err.message); });
MongoDB.once('open', function() {
    console.log("mongodb connection open");
});
```

It would be really great if anyone could help me solve this :( 
I searched the internet and found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost/chatapp";
var MongoDB = mongoose.connect(mongoURI).connection;
MongoDB.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err.message); });
MongoDB.once('open', function() {
    console.log("mongodb connection open");
});
```

also before running the application in your terminal type `npm install mongoose --save`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
    mongoose.connection.once('open',()=>{
        console.log('Connected to db');
    });
```

Comment: Now it just says that "mongoURI is not defined"

Comment: Is your local database running when your are executing the code.

Comment: If you have'nt installed mongodb locally then you can refer to [mlab](https://mlab.com), It is a kind of online mongodb, you will be provided with the mongoURI. [Check it out on how to use it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnOko_y1CfI)

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear. MongoDb is undefined.

Speaking on your MongoDb variable. Should be mongoDb with lowercase. It is one instance.

Anyway, the problem is in `mongoose.connect(mongoURI).connection`. Debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
const config = require('../config');
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');

Mongoose.connect(config.dbURI);
Mongoose.connection.once('open',()=>{
    console.log('Connected to db');
});
```

it helps me.